# error: expected primary-expression before ')' token|

Tags: c++, c, expression, calculator, operation

So I Typed This Code and this error appears ... please help ... and thanks in advance :)

```
double num1;
double num2;
double operation;
//input

   cout<<"Type The First number\n";
   cin>>num1;
   cout<<"Type Second number\n";
   cin>>num2;
   cout<<"Type The Operation..\n";
   cin>>operation;
   //Brain
   if (operation == + )
    {
      cout<<"The Answer is..."<<num1+num2;
```

And The Error is error: expected primary-expression before ')' token|

Comment: `+` is not a `double`. Did you mean to declare `char operation`? Then it would be `if (operation == '+')`.

Comment: The Error Appears in The 12th line

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing a `double` with a `+`. This isn't PHP. :)

Did you mean

```
std::string operation;

//...
if ( operation == "+" )
    //....
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't understand this

```
if (operation == + )
```

You probably want to declare `operation` as a `char`, and then test it like

```
if (operation == '+' )
```